# Primefaces p:datatable reset column width after ajax

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I try to migrate PF from 3.4 to 8.0 and I've surprised the behavior of datatable for resizableColumns="true". In my simple example I change width of a column and then update the table with ajax. PF 3.4 - keeps changed width of column, PF 4.0/6.0/8.0 - resets the width of changed column.
I can save the changed width of column using **colResize** event and then restore width of column after ajax, but maybe is exist more simple solution?
The same behavoir with draggableColumns="true"
The scope of bean is SessionScoped, jsf - 2.2, GlassFish 4.1

```html
<h:form id="mainForm" >
            <p:dataTable id="carTable" value="#{mainController.cars}" var="car" resizableColumns="true">
                <p:column id="colId" headerText="Id" width="200">
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.id}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column id="colModel" headerText="Model" width="200">
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column id="colYear" headerText="Year" width="200">
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.year}"/>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>

            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkBox" value="#{mainController.checkBox}" title="reloadTable" itemLabel="reloadTable">
                <p:ajax event="change"  update="mainForm:carTable"/>
            </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        </h:form>
```

Comment: Did you read all the migration guides?

Comment: @Kukeltje, I guess you tell me about this -  3.4->3.5 "Scrollable and Resizable DataTable-TreeTable features are reimplemented."

Comment: No really sure, although I would not suspect between 3.4 and 3.5, but for 4, there might have been changes... I just cannot remember. Hence the question if you checked the migration guide. But if this is in there that is indeed the case.